# Dynamic height of editor block

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

I use InnovaEditor to create edit block.

I try to find way in order to set dynamic height of edit block.

Ie block height should correspond block content.

**HTML:**

```
<iframe id="idContenteditor_field_1" name="idContenteditor_field_1" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:none;">
<html>
<head></head>
<body>12345</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

What I did:

1) set keyup event in iframe body

2) wrap to content to get real height

3) set calculated height to the iframe

**Javascript:**

```
var $iframe = $("iframe#idContenteditor_field_1");
var $iframeBody = $iframe.contents().find("body");

$iframeBody.keyup(function(e) {

  if ($(this).find('.content').length === 0) {
    // add wrap
    var bodyContent = $(this).html();
    $(this).html('<div class="content">' + bodyContent + '</div>');
 } 

 var $contentBlock = $(this).find('.content');
 var bodyHeight = $contentBlock.outerHeight(); 
 $('#idContenteditor_field_1').height(bodyHeight); // set real height
});
```

It works fine.

The issue:

I have 10 edit blocks on the page and they are same except id.

But I have problems when I try to apply this code to all iframes.

```
// return all iframes
var $iframes = $('iframe[id^="idContenteditor_field_"]');
// return only single body of first iframe. 
var $iframesBody = $iframes .contents().find("body");
```

So I can't set keyup event for all iframes.

Could you help me?

Maybe there is easier way to set dynamic height?

Comment: I have rolled back your latest edit (it's still available in the [revision history](/posts/49383197/revisions)) -- your question should remain a question; though posting an answer of your own is encouraged, and you can accept your own answer if you like (though not immediately).

Answer (score 1):

```
var $iframesBody = $iframes .contents().find("body");
```

^^^ it returns only single body of first iframe, because rest iframes have not yet been loaded fully.

So I just execute this script after load of all iframes.

And it works.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, but something like below should work.
You just need to iterate through your objects and set the event listener for each one in turn.

```
var $iframes = $('iframe[id^="idContenteditor_field_"]');

$iframes.each(function(index, item) {
    var $iframeBody = $(item).contents().find("body");
    $iframeBody.keyup(function(e) {

      if ($(this).find('.content').length === 0) {
        // add wrap
        var bodyContent = $(this).html();
        $(this).html('<div class="content">' + bodyContent + '</div>');
      } 

      var $contentBlock = $(this).find('.content');
      var bodyHeight = $contentBlock.outerHeight(); 
      $(item).height(bodyHeight); // set real height
    });
});
```